# python find all matches of multiple strings in a given string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of the below pattern.

```
string = "'L3-OPS-AB-1499', 'L3-RBP_C-449', 'L2-COM-310', 'L2-PLT-16796'"
```

My requirement is for a regular expression to find all the occurrences of following patterns as below

> a string starting with **L**
>
> followed by a **number**
>
> a **hyphen**
>
> then special **keywords** like **"OPS-AB" or "PLT" or "COM"**
>
> then a hyphen
>
> followed by a number

ex: L3-OPS-AB-1499

I tried the below regex but it gives a partial result

```
regex = re.search("L\d-(OPS|RBP_|-AB|C)|(COM|PLT)-\d+",string)
```

## my output

```
'COM-310'
```

## expected output

```
'L3-OPS-AB-1499', 'L3-RBP_C-449', 'L2-COM-310', 'L2-PLT-16796'
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall`

```
>>> re.findall(r'L\d+-(?:OPS-AB|PLT|COM|RBP_C)-\d+', string)
['L3-OPS-AB-1499', 'L3-RBP_C-449', 'L2-COM-310', 'L2-PLT-16796']
```